# How to use ReturlURL in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

Hi I am trying to configure the login system in asp.net. The way I am using right now is like this in login.aspx.

Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");

It always go to that page after login. I have dvd.aspx and when i click it, i will be directed to login page and after i login, i wanted to to dvd.aspx and not to Default page. How can i configure the return url thing on my login page. I am lost after reading so many things.

Can someone suggest the simple way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For instance if you are dvd.aspx and when you check user is not logged in you should redirect like that.

```
Response.Redirect("/dvd.aspx?returnUrl=" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
```

Or if you don't want to use querystring, write current page to session.

Comment: I dont use querystring. But can u tell me where do i put that code? In login.aspx or dvd.aspx?

Comment: You should put that code where you check user is logged in. If you are using masterpage, paste that code like that. if(Session["user"] == null) { Response.Redirect("/dvd.aspx?returnUrl=" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery); }

Comment: And if you don't use querystring remove that returnUrl part and write it to session like Session["returnUrl"] = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);